# Django without Page Refresh using AJAX

Tags: python, django, ajax

When the teacher update the student behavior, There is a pop up message "Update Success",

in my case when the teacher update the student behavior the page is appear blank

did I miss something ? please check my *return HttpResponse('')* if it is correct and my script.

[image]

this is the source https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgnPSmrQrXI

```
<form method="POST" id="DogForm" action="/Updatestudentbehavior/"  class="myform" style="width: 100%" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <table class="tblcore">
    <input type="text" value="{{teacher}}" name="teacher" id="teacher">
        {% for students in student %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="hidden" value="{{students.id}}" >{{students.Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Lastname}} {{students.Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname}}</td>
            {% for corevalues in studentsbehaviorgrade %}
            <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="id" id="student">
                 <select name="Marking" id="marking">
                     <option value="{{corevalues.Marking.id}}" >{{corevalues.Marking.id}}-{{corevalues.Marking.Marking}}</option>
                     {% for behaviors in behavior %}
                        <option value="{{behaviors.id}}">{{behaviors.id}}-{{behaviors.Marking}}</option>
                     {% endfor %}
                 </select>
             </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on('submit', '#DogForm', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/Updatestudentbehavior/'
            data:{
                teacher:$('#teacher').val(),
                student:$('#student').val(),
                marking:$('#marking').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success:function(){
                alert('Update Success');
            }
        });
   });
</script>
```

my views.py

```
def Updatestudentbehavior(request):
    .....
    return HttpResponse('')
```

urls.py

```
path('Updatestudentbehavior/', Homepage.views.Updatestudentbehavior, name='Updatestudentbehavior'),
```

**UPDATE**
when i tried this

```
def Updatestudentbehavior(request):
    .....
    return HttpResponse('Success')
```

i received this

[image]

it didn't call the ajax i've created in my html
i've try to try console.log

```
<script>
$(document).on('submit', '.myform', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(this);
..
</script>
```

this is the result

[image]

Comment: why i get negative vote without explaining why?

Comment: Typo: "succes" -> "success"

Comment: yes, i fix now the Typo, but it didnt work

Comment: I mean same result

Comment: You can check in the network tab of the browser's devtools, what is being returned.  And there is one exception in the console, can you share that please.

Comment: @Ejaz please check my update question

Comment: I see that you have `id="student"` and `id="marking"` in the `for` loop.  So there are multiple tags with the same id. Each id should be unique. Better change `id` to `class` and update `css` accordingly.

Comment: i think @Ejaz my error is here url:'/Updatestudentbehavior/'

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler is an empty function because you have a syntax error. Change the following lines:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#DogForm', function(e)){
...
}
```

to

```
$(document).on('submit', '#DogForm', function(e) {
...
})
```

Comment: I change it now, but i get the same result :(